# Flutter Complex Linear Gradient Not Working

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

[image]

Above is the expected output.

I need to implement this gradient in Flutter but it's not coming out as excepted.

Color: #6646E7

The color shift is very strict and not smooth as shown in the image.
Below is the container where I wanted to use the

Complete Code:

```
Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 15),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
              // gradient: LinearGradient(
              //     begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              //     end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              //     stops: const [
              //       0.01,
              //       0.1,
              //       0.9
              //     ],
              //     colors: [
              //       const Color(0xff6646E7).withOpacity(0.4),
              //       Colors.white,
              //       const Color(0xff6646E7).withOpacity(0.4),
              //     ]),
              // boxShadow: [
              //   const BoxShadow(
              //       color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
              //       blurRadius: 3,
              //       spreadRadius: 1,
              //       offset: Offset(0, 4))
              // ]),
              ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset('assets/profile/$icon.svg'),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.poppins().fontFamily),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              child
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          right: 10,
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: onEditPressed,
              child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/profile/edit_pen.svg')),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  gradient: LinearGradient(
    colors: [
      Colors.black38,
      Colors.black12,
      Colors.black12,
      Colors.black38,
    ],
    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
  ),
),
```

Change **Colors.black38** & **Colors.black12** with your desired colors.

Comment: Thanks for answering but, the color shift is very strict again

Comment: Rather than predefined colors, give specific colors with hex code, based upon your requirements.

Comment: I tried with my hex code #6646E7 but its still not close to the reference

Comment: Can you please share the complete code in which you kept hex code of colors ?

Comment: I just checked your code, in which, there's no height and width parameter, which makes your container full screen, in my code snippet I have specified `height: 200, width: 400` for test purpose. Try adding these constraints with the snippet. You'll achieve this UI view.

Comment: The above code is a separate widget, I specified height and width when using this widget. Can you share your image?

Comment: Check here, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gNs3MvJnQk1pnUuua6MN73Pfc-bAKTdL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks similar to the reference but, when I use my colors (Color(0xff6646E7).withOpacity(0.4)) then I can see a strict shift which is not what we want.
Hope you get it. Also, thanks for your answers ;)